# Edit joomla content in component via CSS on a template i created

Tags: css, xml, html, joomla1.5, joomla-template

How do i edit the body text (content) of a component in joomla. The css to edit `#content` is responding to other attributes like padding/margin, border, width/height and background but not on font attributes...

in index.php

```
<body>
<div id="content"><jdoc:include type="component" /></div>
</body>
```

css

```
#content
{
    padding:20px 10px 0 20px;
    width:670px;
    border-right:1px groove;
    line-height:30px;
    font-family:Monotype Corsiva;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. if you think the font attributes are important, you can use !important property to overrule the styling :)

```
#content
{
    padding:20px 10px 0 20px;
    width:670px;
    border-right:1px groove;
    line-height:30px;
    font-family:Monotype Corsiva !important;
    font-size:16px !important;
}
```